# Firefox JavaScript debugger: wrong cookie value sent

Tags: session-cookies, firefox-developer-tools

I'm running Firefox 36.0.4 on Windows 7 32-bit. I've diabled all add-ons, extensions and user scripts before retesting this.

I'd like to step through JavaScript code that is served up in a `<script>` tag in the HTML document being produced by a Java (Tomcat) web server.

Unfortunately, when I select the HTML document under `Debugger > Sources`, the source of the page returns to the login page of the application - it appears that session information is not being used to request the source.

I stepped through the server-side code and found that the correct session cookie values were being sent for the real page request and some AJAX requests sent by the page. However, when I tried to load the page source in the JavaScript debugger, I found that an incorrect session cookie was being sent by the JavaScript debugger.

I can replicate this behaviour in other webapps, not just my own. For example, Stack Overflow:
[image: stack overflow bug screenshot]

Is this a configuration issue, or a bug in the Firefox Developer Tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing [canuckistani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562145/canuckistani)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29360220/2045169), I downloaded [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/). Seemingly, the problem was fixed.

Five minutes in, I became sick of being asked whether to remember passwords and having to manually clear session cookies (I prefer being able to do it by simply closing the browser) - it makes testing easier.

As per usual, I went to `Options > Privacy > History` to disable this behaviour, by setting the value to `Never remember history`.

[image: privacy settings screenshot]

Changing this setting requires the browser to restart. However, upon restarting, I once again saw the same erroneous behaviour - the wrong session cookie was being sent to the web application again.

The workaround here is to not use the `Never remember history` setting. [I have filed a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1149835) at [Mozilla.org Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem using StackOverflow as an example, at least in Firefox Developer Edition ( currently version 38 ):

[image]

One thing that might help - try disabling the cache while the toolbox is open - this setting is in the developer tools setting panel ( click on the 'gear' icon at the top right of the toolbox ):

[image]

Comment: It works fine for me in the `Inspector` tab (the example you've used in your screenshot). What I can't view is the JavaScript source in the HTML document under the `Debugger` tab.

Comment: Nevertheless, I can confirm that changing this setting does not fix the problem.

Comment: I'll try the developer edition and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Confirmed: the developer edition works correctly. Are you aware of a bug report that caused this change between versions?